# string array is not properly projected when passing with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Using ajax I want to pass 2 objects: `string[]` and `Options` to my controller. The problem is that every time `string[]` in controller scope is set to `null`.

Thats js code:

```
$("#exportCsv").click(function () {
    var checkboxes = $('.TableChBox:checkbox:checked');
    var allIds = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var el = checkboxes[i];
        if (el.id) {
            allIds.push(el.id);
        }
    }
    console.log(allIds); // it prints ["RId1604678", "RId1604679"]
    
    var form = $('#SearchForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "Bank")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ids: allIds,
            options: form
        }),

        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        async: true,
    });
});
```

And thats c# code:

```
public void ExportToCsv(string[] ids, Options options)
{
    // ids is null here
    // options is not null
}
```

When I use debugger I can see, that `options` is successfully filled, but `ids` is null. Why does that happen?

## Edit 1

As someone suggested I should Add `contentType`. So I added:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "Bank")',
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

And still - `ids` is not null, but `options` is.

## Edit 2

Someone suggested to change two parameters in function to one. So I changed my code to:

part of controller

```
public class ExportModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "one")]
    public string One { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "two")]
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public void ExportToCsv([System.Web.Http.FromBody] ExportModel model)
{
    //model.One is null
    //model.Two is null
}
```

part of `js` code

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    one: "foo",
    two: "bar"
}),
```

And even with that simple example with two strings it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, you don't need `[FromBody]` for MVC. I thought you were using `WebApi`. I thought you'd undone the changes from that. Remove the namespace you had to reference, set your attributes back to how they were, and try my answer as it stands now.

Comment: @john it still doesnt work. Whats more interesting, when I add `contentType: "application/json"` now `Options` is not being parsed properly.

Comment: Well, [this](https://pastebin.com/fkcVyw56) code is working flawlessly for me, so I'm at a loss as to what your problem is now. Note that I'm putting a breakpoint on line 15 and inspecting the value of `t`.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller method you should declare it as accepting a model like so:

```
public void ExportToCsv(ExportModel model)
{

}
```

And then define your model like so:

```
public class ExportModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ids")]
    public string[] Ids {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "options")]
    public Options Options {get;set;}
}
```

As patilprashant6792 pointed out, your ajax request is missing the content type, so you should replace it with this:

```
$("#exportCsv").click(function () {
    var checkboxes = $('.TableChBox:checkbox:checked');
    var allIds = [];
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var el = checkboxes[i];
        if (el.id) {
            allIds.push(el.id);
        }
    }
    console.log(allIds); // it prints ["RId1604678", "RId1604679"]

    var form = $('#SearchForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "Bank")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ids: allIds,
            options: form
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        async: true,
    });
});
```

If you don't declare the content type, it will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: What is `FromBody` attribude? I cant use it. It says `The type or namespace name 'FromBody' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. When I delete that attribute now `ids` and `options` are both null.

Comment: Still both are null.  I addeed `System.Web.Http` and now code started to compile. Bad thing is that I had to change every `[HttpPost]` attribute to `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` because `System.Web.Http` is in conflict with `System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: Please add contentType as 'application/json' in you ajax function and the above code works even without the from body tag

Comment: @patilprashant6792 Unfortunelly your suggestions are not working for me. I edited my code.

Comment: @john thats `asp.net mvc5` project, not `web api`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use list of string instead of array & try.

```
public List<string> Ids {get;set;}
```